# ion-segment with multiple lines

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Trying to fit 6  elements in 1 or 2 lines (depends on the screen width) without success. Got partial success by adding  and  elements. Elements separate nicely in 2 lines if necessary but a strange glitch appears: if I click on the selected button once again selection disappears entirely.

Here is a code:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="doorColour" value="white">
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
        <ion-segment-button value="white">
          <ion-label>White</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="sandstone">
          <ion-label>Sandstone</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="almond">
          <ion-label>Almond</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="bronze">
          <ion-label>Bronze</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="black">
          <ion-label>Black</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="forest green">
          <ion-label>Forest Green</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-segment>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollable` with `mode='md'` to scrollable segment

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="doorColour" value="white" scrollable mode="md">
    <ion-segment-button value="white">
      <ion-label>White</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="sandstone">
      <ion-label>Sandstone</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="almond">
      <ion-label>Almond</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="bronze">
      <ion-label>Bronze</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="black">
      <ion-label>Black</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="forest green">
      <ion-label>Forest Green</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```

Comment: I noticed that you removed <ion-grid> & <ion-row> tags also. That does not help to keep 6 segments in a few rows, scrollable interface is not what I'm looking for. Anyway mode="md" seems to do a job, have a strong feeling that mode="ios" should work flawlessly too, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `swipe-gesture="false"`

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="doorColour" value="white" swipe-gesture="false">
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
        <ion-segment-button value="white">
          <ion-label>White</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="sandstone">
          <ion-label>Sandstone</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="almond">
          <ion-label>Almond</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="bronze">
          <ion-label>Bronze</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="black">
          <ion-label>Black</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="forest green">
          <ion-label>Forest Green</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-segment>
```